# How to convert string in 'MMDD' format into a date using the current year

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this procedure that goes `PROCEDURE(monthday varchar2)`. It receives an `varchar2` that represents the month and date concatenated **always** with the format of **MMDD**. I then want to create a `DATE` type variable that uses this month and day, and the year being the current year. 
Like: 
`desired_date DATE;`

 `desired_date = ?`

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: What’s wrong with `to_date(desired_date,'MMDD')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way

```
desired_date := to_date(monthday, 'MMDD');
```

According to this old post in [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=convert-date-to-string-and-compare-or-convert-string-to-date-and-compare), `to_date` should use the current year, if not given:

> ```
> default year   = current year
> default month  = current month
> default day    = 1
> default hour   = 0
> default minute = 0
> default second = 0
>
>
> ops$tkyte%ORA10GR2> select sysdate, to_date( ' ', ' ' ) from dual;
>
> SYSDATE              TO_DATE('','')
> -------------------- --------------------
> 17-aug-2012 13:41:06 01-aug-2012 00:00:00
> ```

Still unable to find this information in Oracle Docs

Answer (score 4):

`EXTRACT` the year from `SYSDATE` and then combine using string concatenation with your input and use `TO_DATE` to convert to a date:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test (
  monthday     IN  VARCHAR2,
  desired_date OUT DATE
)
IS
BEGIN
  desired_date := TO_DATE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) || monthday, 'YYYYMMDD' );
END;
/
```

then:

```sql
DECLARE
  dt DATE;
BEGIN
  test( '0101', dt );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '0101: ' || dt );

  test( '1231', dt );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1231: ' || dt );

  BEGIN
    test( '9876', dt );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '9876: ' || dt );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '9876: ' || SQLERRM );
  END;
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> 0101: 2019-01-01 00:00:00
> 1231: 2019-12-31 00:00:00
> 9876: ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=163e4773f822051932b98777b931675f)*

If you want to return `NULL` for invalid inputs then:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test (
  monthday     IN  VARCHAR2,
  desired_date OUT DATE
)
IS
BEGIN
  desired_date := TO_DATE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) || monthday, 'YYYYMMDD' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- In general don't catch OTHERS but in this case the only exceptions
    -- are going to be from TO_DATE
    desired_date := NULL;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a04fa1d6806405a74902ba6ad6eed0c)*

---

**Update**:

You could simplify the code (as suggested by [Aleksej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58520521/1509264) and [William Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520050/how-to-split-a-varchar-in-half-in-sql-procedure/58520142?noredirect=1#comment103368970_58520142)) by not specifying the year value in `TO_DATE` and use the default which appears to be the current year; however this behaviour is not, obviously, documented in any Oracle documentation pages so I would also include inline documentation within the function so future developers reviewing your function know that you are deliberately using this behaviour:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test (
  monthday     IN  VARCHAR2,
  desired_date OUT DATE
)
IS
BEGIN
  -- Assumes that TO_DATE will, when not specified, default the year to the
  -- current year and the time to midnight.
  desired_date := TO_DATE( monthday, 'MMDD' );
END;
/
```

Comment: How about `test('9876', dt);`?

Comment: @Littlefoot That will raise an exception as its not a valid month/day combination. I'm assuming that an exception would be the expected behaviour in that case as the OP hasn't specified otherwise and catching it in the procedure would just mask the issue of an invalid input. If returning `NULL` is required then the exception could be caught.

Comment: Isn’t the current year the default anyway?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson That appears to be the case but is not obviously mentioned in any Oracle documentation; you could just use `desired_date := TO_DATE( monthday, 'MMDD' );` but I would also make sure the function is documented that you are assuming the default behaviour of current year so that future developers know what the function is intended to do. Without that extra documentation, using `EXTRACT` to get the year makes it explicitly obvious what the behaviour of the function is.

Comment: Fair point, it doesn’t appear to documented anywhere obvious, it’s just always worked this way.